# AppleScript script to AirDrop file to a specific device?

Tags: macos, applescript, automation, airdrop

Is it possible to create an AppleScript script that automatically takes the selected file in Finder and share it via AirDrop with a specific device?

I am also open to non-ApplesScript ways of doing this.